# Linear mixed effects model with heteroscedastic structure for the errors

Tags: r, linear-regression, mixed-models, trial

In a randomized clinical trial in the ophthalmology field, I would like to find the R implementation for a linear mixed effects model given by

```
log(y_ijk) = b0 + b1_j + b2_k + b3_jk + w_i + e_ijk
```

where `y_ijk` is an amount of residual antibiotics, `b1_j` is the effect of structure (`j=1` if cornea and `j=2` if aquous humor), `b2_k` are the effects of treatments (`k=1,2,3`), `b3` are interaction effects, `w_i` are random effects and `e_ijk` are random errors. We have pairs of observations for each individual (the residual antibiotic is measured in both structures for each subject).

My main difficulty is that the model should incorporate a heteroscedastic structure for the errors, so that the variances are different for each treatment group. In this way,

```
e_ijk ~ Normal(0,sigma_k),  k = 1,2,3
```

Thanks

Comment: The package `nlme` has this option, Bates & Pinheiro (2000) describe the implementation of heteroscedastic residuals using this package